# Have OnItemLongClickListener invoked even when in action mode CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL

Tags: android, android-actionmode, onitemlongclicklistener

I registered an OnItemLongClickListener to a listview but when in actionmode, the listener isn't invoked.

This is the expected behavior, as seen in the [perfromLongPress](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#L2958) method.

**Anyone knows how can I make the lonk click listener to be invoked?**

The reason I want this behavior is to make multiple files selection in one long click. See the [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en) app for an example.

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I used to do the whole thing by hand and it worked great, but I've been overhauling this section of code and MultiChoiceMode  benefits are hard to pass up.

Comment: I just tried to create a custom GridView with modified longPress handling but unfortunately there's no way to access the actionMode state (mChoiceActionMode) which is obviously necessary to handle the logic.

Answer (score -1):

I Think you should use registered instead a MultiChoiceModeListener and Override its method:

```
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // this is where you will inflate the CAB just in case
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers my question. I already defined the MultiChoiceModeListener and the OnItemLongClickListener isn't invoked.

Comment: can you provide some code? it should be invoke if you did it already

Comment: I'll add code as soon as you explain why do you think your answer answers my question. Please explain it in your answer instead of comments.

Comment: Ok MR kilka im sorry i misunderstood you question in the first place... have a Look at this http://www.miximum.fr/porting-the-contextual-anction-mode-for-pre-honeycomb-android-apps.html and change onitemClick to onLongClick maybe it will help.